# How to download WebGrid Data in a PDF file?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor, webgrid

I have a Web application which implemented in **MVC (Razor)** environment.
Inside this application, there is a page that shows data from **SQL Server(using Entity Framework)** with **WebGrid**.

I want to know that how can I embed a button to download this WebGrid data as a **PDF** file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a third party component to generate the PDF since .NET doesn't natively include anything that does that. I recommend iTextSharp. Then you just obtain the data from the database and construct a PdfPTable object which you include in a Pdf document.

I have written an article that includes complete code here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/205/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-PDF-Using-iTextSharp